# Conditional questions and branching in SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a Sharepoint list with a list of yes/no questions. I want to make some questions conditional on another question being selected. So if Question A is Yes then Question B is required (if No then not required or, if possible, greyed out). Basically, I want to recreate the branching you get in Microsoft Forms where a question appears depending on whether another is selected.

Is that possible in SharePoint lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it's possible!**

After creating the list structure with yours questions and choices Yes/No, click on the `New` button to display the form. On the top right, click on `Edit column`

[image: Edit columns]

Next, select your column `Question2` and click on `Edit conditional formula`

[image: Edit conditional formula]

Enter the following formula to display Question2 only if Question1 equals to `Yes`:

```
=if([$Question1] == 'Yes', 'true', 'false')
```

[image: Formula]

So, now, when entering the form, Question2 is hidden.

[image: Question2 hidden]

If you select `No`, Question2 is still hidden.

[image: Question2 still hidden]

If you select `Yes`, Question2 is displayed!

[image: Question2 is visible]

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this through list validation.

Here are steps:

1.Go to List Settings.

2.Click "Validation Settings" under "General Settings".

3.Enter the validation formula as: =IF([Question A]=TRUE,IF([Question B]="",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)